# Easiest way to use Dapper ORM

Tags: c#, object, dapper

What is the easiest way to get the output of a Dapper ORM query into the data members of the class that provides the method for the query?

This is my code with a method A (ugly) and B (does not work):

```
public class MyLab_ClientRef
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    // ... more fields ...

    public bool GetUser(OracleConnection conn, int UserId, string ClientId)
    {
        bool Ok = false;
        IEnumerable<MyLab_ClientRef> QueryResultRecords =
            conn.Query<MyLab_ClientRef>(@"
                SELECT *
                FROM MyLab_ClientRef
                WHERE UserId   = :UserId
                  AND ClientId = :ClientId",
            new { UserId = UserId, ClientId = ClientId });
        if (QueryResultRecords.Count() == 1)
        {
            // Method A
            MyLab_ClientRef Rec = QueryResultRecords.First(); // works
            CopyRec(Rec, this);                               // ugly

            // Method B
            this = QueryResultRecords.First();            // avoids CopyRec, does not work

            Ok = true;
        }
        return Ok;
    }

    private static void CopyRec(MyLab_ClientRef CR_From, MyLab_ClientRef CR_To)
    {
        CR_To.UserId = CR_From.UserId;
        CR_To.ClientId = CR_From.ClientId;
    }
}
```

I like to keep the record definition close to the query that gets the record, but don't like to implement a `CopyRec` method for every table class this way.

Is there no better way to implement this? I tried to write `this = ...` but that is not possible.

How to write a method B that is better than method A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following would not work:

```
this = QueryResultRecords.First();
```

Check following links for why:

[Why can't I set "this" to a value in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285087/why-cant-i-set-this-to-a-value-in-c)

[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ed576c0-820f-4392-831a-27e3d4a229d9/cannot-assign-to-this-because-it-is-readonly?forum=clr)

As shown in the first link above, your best options remains that you return the `MyLab_ClientRef` from a given method, can make it static  and use if for `value or reference` assignment, in this case either should yield same result

Check the following if this can be a cleaner implementation in your view:

```
public class MyLab_ClientRef
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    // ... more fields ...

    public static MyLab_ClientRef GetUser(OracleConnection conn, int UserId, string ClientId)
    {
        bool Ok = false;

        var QueryResultRecords =
            conn.Query<MyLab_ClientRef>(@"SELECT * FROM MyLab_ClientRef WHERE UserId = :UserId AND ClientId = :ClientId",new { UserId = UserId, ClientId = ClientId });

            if(QueryResultRecords.Any())
                return QueryResultRecords.First();
            else
                return null;        

    }  
}
```

It can be called as:

```
var newClient = MyLab_ClientRef.GetUser(conn, UserId,ClientId);
```

It would be preferred though is the `connection` object is local to a method and is use in the `using` clock

Comment: Your first link is very relevant for my question. Together with your solution and the comments on my similar / simplified question http://stackoverflow.com/q/33392575/1845672 I am now convinced that C# cannot assign to `this` and that a separate Service class might be useful.